# What are these robots in the Matrix?

Tags: movie, the-matrix

What are these robots and what do they do?

[image]

They are in the scene where the human babies are grown by the robots. They don't look mechanical,but I am guessing that they are part of the process for making humans, maybe cleaning robots.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's actually a bit of backstory to these little critters that didn't make it into the film. In short, they're robotic parasites.

> **Barrow:** *Larry and Andy [Wachowski] talked about how the creatures were constantly
>   changing and shimmering as in this drawing, where **there's a lot of
>   little robots crawling all over the Fetus Stalk, like arachnids***
>
> *Amongst these robots, there's a sort of pecking order. This doesn't
>   fully come across in the movie, but it's part of the backstory Larry
>   and Andy have come up with. **Some of the robots are bad and are
>   actually siphoning off energy, so other robots come along and pick
>   them off.***
>
> *They also talked a lot about there being a bit of prejudice amongst
>   the robots, those that have developed less than humanistic forms look
>   down on the ones with a vestigial human appearance*

[image]

[image]

<sub><sup>Images from '[The Art of the Matrix](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/The_Art_of_The_Matrix)'</sup></sub>